# Проблемы с SDK при создании проекта в Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

В SDK Manager установлен API 17. Но при создании проекта в Eclipse "Compile with" пустой. Я не имею достаточного опыта работы в этой среде и не могу понять что ей нужно, как ни странно это не звучит, но Еclipse просто не создает проект.Как быть?

Comment: а почему не используете официальную среду разработки -  Android Studio?

Comment: Нужно на Eclipse.

Comment: [Support Ended for Eclipse Android Developer Tools](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/support-ended-for-eclipse-android.html), так что ждать правильной работы не стоит.

Comment: @НодираШорахмедова, используйте Android Studio. Причин использовать Eclipse попросту нет. В Android Studio можно "скормить" Eclipse'e проект (если он на столько уж старый).